# IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter

Hice un programa que lleva el stock de ciertos artículos y hay un botón para decrementar unidades, el cual no debe hacer esto si la existencia del articulo llegó a cero. Ahí es donde empieza el problema, estoy usando un treeview para mostrar los datos.

```
def decrement_record():
    selected = tabla.focus()
    values = tabla.item(selected, 'values')
    print(values[3])

    if (int(values[3]) - 1) <= 0:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No hay mas unidades de este artículo")
    
    else:
        cantidad = (int(values[3]) - 1)
        modificar_unidad(values[0], cantidad)
```

cuando selecciono un articulo con cero unidades, el código se ejecuta como es esperado, pero después de eso se rompe completamente. mostrándome este error:

> if (int(values[3]) - 1) <= 0:
> IndexError: string index out of range

Intenté atrapar la excepción pero tampoco sirvió...

Comment: No entiendo. Debería romper antes, en el print. O es que ese print lo añadiste después de la ejecución que te daba el error?

Comment: la primer vez que seleccionas un articulo con cantidad cero, se ejecuta con normalidad, a la siguiente que haces lo mismo el print no imprime nada y se rompe en el if

Comment: Puedes cambiar el `print` para que imprima `values` y decirnos que sale en estos tres casos?  artculo con cantidad > 0, primera vez con cantidad =0, y segunda vez

Comment: @abulafia, el error estaba en que reconstruía la tabla para refrescar los datos y me daba problemas, pero ya lo reemplacé con el método item(). Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!